# Angular JS: Changing input value from jquery does not update ng-model

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS.  I am trying to write a directive that is a list of input fields, and when you press the comma key (the 188 number in the plunkr), it will trigger a "done" function so that it will update the model.  I have an ng-repeat in my directive with this list of values.

I have also read a few posts about using scope.$apply but that does not seem to be working in this situation.  Any help on how to access the item in the ng-repeat that's being changed or how to update the ng-model directly on that list item?

If you view my plunkr, change the names and put a comma at the end.  In the area at the top, you can see the values of the model.  You can see that the comma is still there which is not my expected behavior because it is not in the input field itself.

Code here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/PBzRD8fBQ6D1GCEC869K?p=preview

Comment: you just want to prevent , from entering in input tag?

Comment: The comma is removed when the input loses focus.. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the changes I suggest, perhaps thats the usecase you desire

http://plnkr.co/edit/YXtVTJSQNyJo7njdiu4Z

If you have any questions I will give more feedback on request ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding, this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Johann Sonntagbauer, please quote the most relevant part of an important link, and use links only to provide more context to your answer. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer section "Provide context for links" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to stop the user from typing a comma, you can do this without jQuery:

```
$html.on('keydown', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 188) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

There's also (as far as I can tell with limited context) no reason for $compile.  You should be able to just use a template:

http://jsfiddle.net/VM285/

```
myApp.directive('mydirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            list: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 188) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
        template: '<div><ul ng-model="list"><li ng-repeat="item in list"><input ng-model="item.Name" type="text" /></li></ul></div>'
    }
});
```

And taking it 1 step further, you can do this entirely without DOM manipulation:

http://jsfiddle.net/VM285/1/

```
myApp.directive('mydirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            list: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.checkForComma = function(item) {
                if (item.Name.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                    item.Name = item.Name.replace(/,/g, '');
                }
            };
        },
        template: '<div><ul ng-model="list"><li ng-repeat="item in list"><input ng-model="item.Name" type="text" ng-change="checkForComma(item)" /></li></ul></div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Langdon, thanks for responding, this would work but I wanted it to perform an action when the comma is hit and then remove the comma from the value.